# Windows Phone - Contact choose

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developping an app for Windows Phone 8.0 and I wanted to offer the users the possibility to pick contacts from their contacts in the phone. However, my app will have the possibility to use either SMS or email to contact people, so I cannot use the native choosers from Windows Phone because they return either an email or a SMS and I want to whole data.

I have seen the `Contacts` class with Async research, but I would prefer have the user select his contacts from a native look and feel (I know, I'm picky). Is there any native way to do that and if not, is there any third-party library that makes this possible easily ?

If not, I will create my own implementation of it, but I'd rather not write something that has already been done.

Thanks, gretro.

Comment: Might be easier to restructure your UI such that the user first decides if they want to use email or SMS, THEN display the appropiate contact chooser UI.

Comment: The fact is that sending an email or a SMS is a functionality, not the purpose of the app. I want to import the Contact's name and picture for display AND offer the possibility to send them a SMS or an email pre-filled with the content the app generates.